# Receiving "NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" when pushing Rails app to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am getting the following log file when trying to push to Heroku even though the app is running properly when I launch it through the shell on Cloud 9:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.4.4
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.4). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Using rake 12.3.1
remote:        Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
remote:        Using minitest 5.10.3
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Using builder 3.2.3
remote:        Using erubi 1.7.1
remote:        Using mini_portile2 2.3.0
remote:        Using crass 1.0.4
remote:        Using rack 2.0.5
remote:        Using nio4r 2.3.1
remote:        Using websocket-extensions 0.1.3
remote:        Using mini_mime 1.0.1
remote:        Using arel 8.0.0
remote:        Using execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Using popper_js 1.14.3
remote:        Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
remote:        Using ffi 1.9.25
remote:        Using bundler 1.15.2
remote:        Using method_source 0.9.0
remote:        Using thor 0.20.0
remote:        Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
remote:        Using multi_json 1.13.1
remote:        Using pg 0.18.4
remote:        Using puma 3.9.1
remote:        Using tilt 2.0.8
remote:        Using turbolinks-source 5.2.0
remote:        Using i18n 1.1.0
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.5
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.8.4
remote:        Using rack-test 1.1.0
remote:        Using sprockets 3.7.2
remote:        Using websocket-driver 0.6.5
remote:        Using autoprefixer-rails 9.1.4
remote:        Using uglifier 3.2.0
remote:        Using mail 2.7.0
remote:        Using rb-inotify 0.9.10
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Using turbolinks 5.0.1
remote:        Using activesupport 5.1.6
remote:        Using loofah 2.2.2
remote:        Using sass-listen 4.0.0
remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Using globalid 0.4.1
remote:        Using activemodel 5.1.6
remote:        Using jbuilder 2.7.0
remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
remote:        Using sass 3.6.0
remote:        Using activejob 5.1.6
remote:        Using activerecord 5.1.6
remote:        Using actionview 5.1.6
remote:        Using bootstrap 4.1.3
remote:        Using actionpack 5.1.6
remote:        Using actioncable 5.1.6
remote:        Using actionmailer 5.1.6
remote:        Using railties 5.1.6
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.2.2
remote:        Using jquery-rails 4.3.1
remote:        Using rails 5.1.6
remote:        Using sass-rails 5.0.6
remote:        Using bootstrap_form 4.0.0.alpha1
remote:        Bundle complete! 23 Gemfile dependencies, 61 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Bundle completed (3.06s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.4). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        The latest bundler is 1.17.0.pre.1, but you are currently running 1.15.2.
remote:        To update, run `gem install bundler --pre`
remote: -----> Installing node-v8.10.0-linux-x64
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
remote:        Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.142230 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/FontAwesome-ecd72f31910a8ee2726fd17bd459be26f230779f3f3ed5f69ebf829e4b12e768.otf
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.143259 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/FontAwesome-ecd72f31910a8ee2726fd17bd459be26f230779f3f3ed5f69ebf829e4b12e768.otf.gz
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.146824 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/fontawesome-webfont-50bbe9192697e791e2ee4ef73917aeb1b03e727dff08a1fc8d74f00e4aa812e1.eot
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.147645 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/fontawesome-webfont-50bbe9192697e791e2ee4ef73917aeb1b03e727dff08a1fc8d74f00e4aa812e1.eot.gz
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.155999 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/fontawesome-webfont-8e3586389bb4cd01b3f85bb3b622739bde6627f28bba63a020c223ca9cf1b9ae.svg
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.156816 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/fontawesome-webfont-8e3586389bb4cd01b3f85bb3b622739bde6627f28bba63a020c223ca9cf1b9ae.svg.gz
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.161253 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/fontawesome-webfont-ae19e2e4c04f2b04bf030684c4c1db8faf5c8fe3ee03d1e0c409046608b38912.ttf
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.162158 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/fontawesome-webfont-ae19e2e4c04f2b04bf030684c4c1db8faf5c8fe3ee03d1e0c409046608b38912.ttf.gz
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.171358 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/fontawesome-webfont-adbc4f95eb6d7f2738959cf0ecbc374672fce47e856050a8e9791f457623ac2c.woff
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.178232 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/fontawesome-webfont-7dacf83f51179de8d7980a513e67ab3a08f2c6272bb5946df8fd77c0d1763b73.woff2
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.180823 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular-13634da87d9e23f8c3ed9108ce1724d183a39ad072e73e1b3d8cbf646d2d0407.eot
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.181403 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular-13634da87d9e23f8c3ed9108ce1724d183a39ad072e73e1b3d8cbf646d2d0407.eot.gz
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.185251 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular-42f60659d265c1a3c30f9fa42abcbb56bd4a53af4d83d316d6dd7a36903c43e5.svg
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.185519 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular-42f60659d265c1a3c30f9fa42abcbb56bd4a53af4d83d316d6dd7a36903c43e5.svg.gz
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.187944 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular-e395044093757d82afcb138957d06a1ea9361bdcf0b442d06a18a8051af57456.ttf
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.188205 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular-e395044093757d82afcb138957d06a1ea9361bdcf0b442d06a18a8051af57456.ttf.gz
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.191454 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular-a26394f7ede100ca118eff2eda08596275a9839b959c226e15439557a5a80742.woff
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.194453 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular-fe185d11a49676890d47bb783312a0cda5a44c4039214094e7957b4c040ef11c.woff2
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.203703 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/icofont-e4cbd1671344845acbca57717d36b47677d9bb3d083f733ae10b9465d94a7762.eot
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.211381 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/icofont-e4cbd1671344845acbca57717d36b47677d9bb3d083f733ae10b9465d94a7762.eot.gz
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.283967 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/icofont-667f31ea1b0f726e62ca628f730aa94d25b7e408886962233387ff5ed9541638.svg
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.354445 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/icofont-667f31ea1b0f726e62ca628f730aa94d25b7e408886962233387ff5ed9541638.svg.gz
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.399102 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/icofont-ac2e76e07a7208cc4c0f7afb773a89a314c4d13bf7f6def920ad50817e6ba735.ttf
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.402251 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/icofont-ac2e76e07a7208cc4c0f7afb773a89a314c4d13bf7f6def920ad50817e6ba735.ttf.gz
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.417501 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/icofont-00f9608b3cbbb28d65eca172de8b338e505e76c228ca385e25f3f6784e29552c.woff
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.439650 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/footer-bg-dafa00f60bd0f41505cbdecb70a629b5f08e682d3ac2c86a6366c6ad3b369d0e.jpg
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.450314 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/hand-mockup-581076b7c0893772e9759a46fb5d989e8a1454389c606f3b04c7762450b8e0a5.png
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.454120 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/loader-bef56aeeae1ddf3cf1a282a73f84d7a0a33b2b3fc2104f9c169bb8a8c05e5a32.gif
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.461330 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/logo-3d7e2c3ed22e51603ebdf03572ac74b9d966e327fe2f196d5a6a701555113163.png
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.464691 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/showcase-89c921bf383a4dc538f3629fbf6ab3a31a748539b349581d4458794ba455ec30.png
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:18.471609 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/showcase2-3592117095ec5c8714c5b4c4e5b0c5230822f80d4e991b7308609194b825b03e.png
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:22.991915 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/application-b10a17f71861db0a548cebad3165cf93d24b4d23401df4869e6d7b6c053b36a5.js
remote:        I, [2018-10-03T09:12:22.992699 #384]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/public/assets/application-b10a17f71861db0a548cebad3165cf93d24b4d23401df4869e6d7b6c053b36a5.js.gz
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:278:in `sprockets_context'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:124:in `asset_path'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:137:in `asset_url'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:209:in `font_url'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:151:in `block in _perform'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/stack.rb:108:in `block in with_function'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/stack.rb:135:in `with_frame'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/stack.rb:108:in `with_function'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:149:in `_perform'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb:50:in `perform'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:398:in `visit_prop'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/stack.rb:135:in `with_frame'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:513:in `block (2 levels) in visit_directive'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:513:in `map'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:513:in `block in visit_directive'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:512:in `visit_directive'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/stack.rb:135:in `with_frame'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:167:in `block in visit_children
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:166:in `visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:186:in `visit_root'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:157:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:10:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.6.0/lib/sass/engine.rb:290:in `render'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:48:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:186:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_12dabe8ded8a8b689b0a385e82947a02/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
```

I believe `remote: NoMethodError: undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass` is the most important part of this error.

I've already tried several things from other answers on the site to no avail.

Such as adding `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` to my `config/application.rb` file.

I tried compiling the assests locally before trying to push to Heroku, but I received the same error.

I noticed that many of the other people who had a similar issue at least had a reference to a specific file and line with the NoMethod error, but I have no such thing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error during `rake assets:precompile`, so you can try this rake task on local machine.

From stack trace I've found `font_url`, you can try to find this method in your `.css` file and rename it to `.scss`

Comment: It's not good idea to precompile assets on local machine as it won't assets changes after this precompilation. while posting links with answer make sure you have brief expiation for the answer, external links may not work in future.